# How to get the underlying value copied from Excel in javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, clipboard

From clipboard 
`(e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain')`
I get

```
2-Oct
2-Nov
2-Dec
2-Jan
2-Feb
2-Mar
2-Apr
2-May
2-Jun
2-Jul
2-Aug
2-Sep
```

But the true value when I click on each cell are

```
10/2/2016
11/2/2016
12/2/2016
1/2/2017
2/2/2017
3/2/2017
4/2/2017
5/2/2017
6/2/2017
7/2/2017
8/2/2017
9/2/2017
```

Is there a way to get the true value?

Comment: Mabey one of the other [clipboard formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836533.aspx) has the data you desire.

Comment: @SamAxe I tried all `text/rtf, text/html, text/plain, and image/png`. I don't know if anything else is available in Chrome.